# Wrong .git folder

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm setting up a new dev server and, at the same time, cutting out access for a former agency.  This includes setting up a new repo and getting rid of theirs.
So I used rsync to copy files from the live server to a dev one.  I then deleted the .git folder, created a new repo and set it up to push there.  During this time there were some changes done to the live server so I decided to rsync once more.  I completely forgot about the .git folder and I cancelled the rsync as soon as I realized, but I was too late and it copied some of the .git from the old repo to the new one that was created.  Now I'm getting errors, listed below.

```
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/snagging-882' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/snagging-896' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/snagging-899' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/snagging-911' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/develop' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/staging' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/review' references pruned commits
error: Could not read c1fd5ccb43ddea672fa5b141a0fdb0d65d813b8a
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 57c5f1c268a7775ebab6ee4f42d94dec2159844f
error: failed to run repack
```

Can I restore my .git folder somehow or do I need to create again?

Thanks

Comment: Before you delete anything, do you have any commits in the new repo that you _haven't_ pushed to the new remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you *have pushed* the new repo to a remote, the safest way to solve this problem is to clone the *new repo* into a new local directory and set it up to use the working tree from the one with the corrupted `.git` directory.

Here's a step-by-step guide:

```
1. git clone <url-to-new-repo> FreshNewRepo && cd FreshNewRepo
   # Clone the new repo into a new local directory called 'FreshNewRepo'

2. git --work-tree=/path/to/corrupted-repo add -A
   # Set up the 'FreshNewRepo' to use the working tree from the corrupted repo
   # (thereby getting the rsynced files from the old repo), then stage all changes

3. git status
   # At this point, you should have all the changes from corrupted repo
   # in the index of your 'FreshNewRepo'

4. git commit
   # Create a commit to mark that you imported the latest changes from the old repo.

5. (optional) rm -rf /path/to/corrupted-repo
   # Once you're certain that no changes are left behind in the corrupted repo,
   # (either commits not being pushed or uncommitted changes in the working tree)
   # there's no reason to keep it around.
```

```

Here's some [more information](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreworktree) about the [`--work-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---work-treeltpathgt) option.